# Django REST Api

Tags: python, django, rest

Друзья! Доброго времени суток!
У меня есть практически готовый Django проект...
Можно ли переделать этот проект под Django REST Api без потерь? Реально ли это? Или лучше с нуля?

Answer (score 1):

Используйте [django-rest-framework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/). Рекомендую вам создать отдельное приложение внутри проекта, в котором будет описан API.